# Update via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Help me about this, I'm really confused !

I just want to update something! This is my controller (post action):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel)
{
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _categoryService.UpdateCategory(categoryViewModel.Id);
            }
            return View();
}
```

and this is my service class (my question is about this class, I don't know how to update it)

```
public CategoryViewModel UpdateCategory(Guid categoryId)
{
            var category = _unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.FindBy(categoryId);
            var categoryViewModel = category.ConvertToCategoryViewModel();
             _unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Update(category);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            return categoryViewModel;
}
```

and finally my base repository like this :

```
private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;

public void Update(T entity)
{
            _entitySet.Attach(entity);
}
```

also my `UnitOfWork` is this :

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private IRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;

    public IRepository<Category> CategoryRepository
    {
            get { return _categoryRepository ?? (_categoryRepository = new Repository<Category>(_statosContext)); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that updates the properties on the `category` object?

Comment: Also, I presume that your `_unitOfWork` variable is a `DbContext` or `ObjectContext` derived object. Is that true? If not, what is the body of your `SaveChanges` function?

Comment: yes , my _UnitOfWork variabel id DbCotext , but my trouble is in service class , basically I have trouble with the algorithm of that, although I Edit my question with also my UnitOfwork

Comment: as I mentioned my trouble is with UpdateCategory(Guid categoryId), I don't know how to update the name of category with new one by getting the earlier one and replacing with new ...

Comment: Again, in your `UpdateCategory` I don't see where you update the properties on the `category` variable. Where is that happening? If you never update a property then EF will do nothing when `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: where do you attach your categoryViewModel?

Comment: well my question is what you just talked about ! how ? how can I do that , take a closer look at my UpdateCategory() please

Answer (score 0):

Change `UpdateCategory` to accept the `CategoryViewModel` instead of just the `Guid`. Add an instance `UpdateFromViewModel(CategoryViewModel model)` method to the `Category` object whose job it is to take the properties from the model and transfer them to the EF entity. After that, the rest of your code should work. There are other patterns that can be used to accomplish this as well, but given your existing patterns, this should get you across the finish line.

```
public class Category
{
    public void LoadFromModel(CategoryViewModel model)
    {
        // Transfer properties from model to entity here
    }
}

public class CategoryService
{
    public void UpdateCategory(CategoryViewModel model)
    {
        var category = _unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.FindBy(model.CategoryId);
        category.LoadFromModel(model);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        model.CategoryId = category.CategoryId;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I changed my Service method like this public Category UpdateCategory(CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel)
        {

            var category = categoryViewModel.ConvertToCategoryModel();
             _unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Update(category);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            return category;
        }

Comment: but Now I have this trouble with  public void Update(T entity)
        {
            _entitySet.Attach(entity);
        }
that says to me An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.  what is the rule of Dbset<> to Update an entity ??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My intent was for your to load the entity from the Context first using the Guid, then call an instance function on the `Category` class to map Model properties to Entity properties. This way you will be working with the properly attached object. With this change you can remove your `Update` call in `CategoryRepository`.

Comment: sorry I didn't got it ! so you know any sample about that ?

Comment: are u sure about that ?? my Category class in Domain layer whereas my CategoryViewModl is in Service layer ! Model should be POCO and shouldn't have any reference to any layer such as Service

Comment: Yes. To avoid circular references, add a `ToEntity(Category category)` function to your view model that takes the category object you loaded based Id.